# Need some explanation on my wait and notify code

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Please follow the code below,

Resource.java,

```
public class Resource {

public void first() {

    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    try {
        System.out.println(t.getName() + " : is accessing the method 'first' ");

        synchronized (this) {
            for (int num = 1; num <= 10; num++) {
                System.out.println(t.getName() + " : NUM : " + num);
                Thread.sleep(500);
                if (num == 5) {
                    this.wait();
                }
            }
            this.notify();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void second() {

    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    try {
        System.out.println(t.getName() + " : is accessing the method 'second' ");

        synchronized (this) {
            for (int num = 1; num <= 10; num++) {
                System.out.println(t.getName() + " : X : " + num);
                Thread.sleep(500);
                if (num == 7) {
                    this.notify();
                    this.wait();                       
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

ReqThread.java as follows,

```
public class ReqThread extends Thread{

public ReqThread(String name,Resource res){
    this.setName(name);
    this.res = res;
}

private Resource res;

@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        if("ONE".equals(this.getName())){
            res.first();
        }else{
            res.second();
        }            
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And MainClass.java,

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String [] args){
    Resource res = new Resource();
    ReqThread t1 = new ReqThread("ONE", res);
    ReqThread t2 = new ReqThread("TWO", res);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

You can see from the above code, i am trying to learn on thread communication using wait and notify mechanism.

Here one the thread 'ONE' starts first starts, than an counter 5 waits and releases the lock, and than thread 'TWO' proceeds (which was already in the waiting state) and than its counter reaches 7 notifies and waits.

So my question is when thread 'TWO' do notify in method 'second', does is releases the lock ?

the output of the above code is

```
ONE : is accessing the method 'first' 
ONE : NUM : 1
TWO : is accessing the method 'second' 
ONE : NUM : 2
ONE : NUM : 3
ONE : NUM : 4
ONE : NUM : 5
TWO : X : 1
TWO : X : 2
TWO : X : 3
TWO : X : 4
TWO : X : 5
TWO : X : 6
TWO : X : 7
ONE : NUM : 6
ONE : NUM : 7
ONE : NUM : 8
ONE : NUM : 9
ONE : NUM : 10
TWO : X : 8
TWO : X : 9
TWO : X : 10
```

Now, if I do the code change in Resource.java in method 'second' as below

```
if (num == 7) {
                    this.notify();
                    //this.wait();                       
                }
```

the output of the code is

```
ONE : is accessing the method 'first' 
ONE : NUM : 1
TWO : is accessing the method 'second' 
ONE : NUM : 2
ONE : NUM : 3
ONE : NUM : 4
ONE : NUM : 5
TWO : X : 1
TWO : X : 2
TWO : X : 3
TWO : X : 4
TWO : X : 5
TWO : X : 6
TWO : X : 7
TWO : X : 8
TWO : X : 9
TWO : X : 10
ONE : NUM : 6
ONE : NUM : 7
ONE : NUM : 8
ONE : NUM : 9
ONE : NUM : 10
```

From the second output you can see, even if thread 'TWO' does notify(), than too it doesn't waits and continues its printing numbers,

is this because even if thread 'TWO' does notify() but than too the code is still in synchronized block, and it still has the lock which is not yet released ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the javadoc. [`Object#notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) states

> **The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object**. The awakened thread will
>   compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be
>   actively competing to synchronize on this object;

So you are correct. Calling `object.notify()` doesn't release the `object`'s monitor. It simply wakes up a thread which still needs to compete to get it.

So `notify()` doesn't release the monitor, but [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) does.

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. **The thread releases
>   ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies
>   threads waiting on this object's monitor** to wake up either through a
>   call to the `notify` method or the `notifyAll` method.

---

When you are comfortable with how object synchronization and `wait()` and `notify()` work, consider moving to the `java.util.concurrent` package which does all this for you.

Comment: +1 and this competition for the lock after a thread has been notified is specifically the reason why we have race conditions around multiple producer/consumer implementations.